# counting characters of textbox erroring out in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I keep getting the error 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'txtMessage' is undefined
 what I am trying to do is to count the characters of a textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit)
    { 
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)    
          field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
          countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
</script>
```

Textbox that I have :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="200px" Rows="3" runat="server"  onkeyup="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" onkeydown="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" />
```

and here I am counting:

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" /> characters left
```

Comment: Can you run your code with Google Chrome? So, check the error in the Chrome console.

Comment: no error in chrome but didn't count..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to a server side control. In my situations, the ID specified on the server will not be the same as the ID on the client. You can correct that in a number of ways. The most straight forward is to change the ClientIDMode.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" ClientIdMode="static" TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="200px" Rows="3" runat="server"  onkeyup="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" onkeydown="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" />
```

Changing the mode to static will mean that it will use the ID that you specified. Beware that you're now responsible for ensuring the ID is unique on the composited page (master page(s) + content page + user control(s)).

When dealing with JavaScript, always inspect the source using your browser. What you're looking at on the server may be different than what you get on the client.

Comment: I'm not ASP dev so i just wondering is it the same than removing `runat="server"`? Or this is complelty out off topic question?! :)

Comment: @A.Wolff If you remove `runat="server"` it will cease to be a server side control, and it won't be processed and the literal markup `<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="200px" Rows="3"   onkeyup="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" onkeydown="textCounter(txtMessage, this.form.remLen, 160);" />` would be sent to the client side, and the client side wouldn't know what to do with it. If you need server side functionality, use a TextBox control. If you don't need server side functionality, use plain HTML (`<input type="text">`).

Comment: how may I replace the <input> by <asp:label> ?

Comment: @JuniorJohn Check out the documentation for the [Label control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx). That should give you an idea.

Comment: I am getting the following error, looks like it is unable to access its value

Comment: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @JuniorJohn Did you set the ClientIdMode as I described for TextBox? It works the same way for Label and any other server control.

Comment: yes I did <asp:Label ID="charcount_lbl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" Text="160"></asp:Label> and the function call is onkeyup="textCounter(txtMessage, charcount_lbl , 160);"

Comment: @JuniorJohn Which line specifically is throwing the error?

Comment: fixed it by accessing the label text this way: document.getElementById('charcount_lbl').innerText = maxlimit - field.value.length;

Answer (score 0):

If you use script on client side, use javascript for access to controls.
Try follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"  Width="200px" Rows="3"  onkeyup="textCounter(this.value, 160);" onkeydown="textCounter(this.value, 160);" />
<input id='remLen' readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" /> characters left
```

And correct your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textCounter(value, maxlimit)
{ 
if (value.length > maxlimit)    
    value = value.substring(0, maxlimit);
else
    var countfield = document.getElementById('remLen');
    countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
</script>
```